# Finding Local IP Address

Tags: pclinuxos

On PCLinuxOS I want to get my local IP address (192.168.0.XXX). Using ip addr show and ifconfig, I get addresses formatted as XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, but no ipv4 address. How can I get this address?

Comment: Give us the output of ifconfig on your system.

Comment: It could be that the computer does not have an IPv4 address assigned...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }'

* where "eth0" is your interface

Also you can get all ipv4:

ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1 }'